# Sorting A-Z/Date data from router.get?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Quick question: how can I sort my posts data by date?

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const posts = await Post.find()
        res.json(posts)
    }
    catch (err) {
        res.json({message: err})
    }
})
```

I came from Django and there you could do something like:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter().order_by('date')
```

I'm fairly new to NodeJS and Express. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the what the data structure of the date property is. If they are in JS timestamp format:-

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const posts = await Post.find();

        const sortedPosts = posts.sort((a,b) => {
          return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
        });

        res.json(sortedPosts)
    }
    catch (err) {
        res.json({message: err})
    }
})
```

Here I've used the array's `sort()` method. [Learn more](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_sort.asp)

Comment: Thank you so much! God bless! :)